# Give Focus to ExpandItem on ExpandBar after expanding the Item

Tags: java, swt

I have a `StyledText` Widget on an `ExpandItem` and this `ExpandItem` belongs to an `ExpandBar`.

I want to `setFocus()` to the `StyledText` if the `ExpandItem` is expanded.

I tried to do so in an `ExpandListener`, but it turns out that inside the `itemExpanded()` method the `ExpandItem` is not yet expanded and so I can't give Focus to the `StyledText` Widget.

I also tried to expand the Item manually inside the `itemExpanded()` Method via

```
item.setExpanded(true);
bar.layout();
```

but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `ExpandListener`s `itemExpanded()` method is fired before the item has been expanded completely.

Consequently, forcing the focus on the `StyledText` fails.

However, there is a simple workaround for this problem. You can use a `Runnable` and start it with `Display#asyncExec(Runnable)`. This will leave enough time for the item to actually reveal the `StyledText`:

```
private static Map<ExpandItem, StyledText> mapping = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final ExpandBar bar = new ExpandBar(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        addExpandItem(bar, i);

    bar.addExpandListener(new ExpandListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void itemExpanded(ExpandEvent e)
        {
            ExpandItem item = (ExpandItem) e.item;

            expandItem(mapping.get(item));
        }

        @Override
        public void itemCollapsed(ExpandEvent e)
        {

        }
    });

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Expand first");
    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            expandItem(bar.getItem(0));
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static void expandItem(ExpandItem item)
{
    ExpandBar bar = item.getParent();

    item.setExpanded(true);
    Event e = new Event();
    e.item = item;
    bar.notifyListeners(SWT.Expand, e);
}

private static void expandItem(final StyledText text)
{
    if (text != null && !text.isDisposed())
    {
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                if (text != null && !text.isDisposed())
                {
                    text.setFocus();
                    text.forceFocus();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

private static void addExpandItem(ExpandBar bar, int i)
{
    ExpandItem item = new ExpandItem(bar, SWT.NONE);
    item.setText("Item " + i);

    Composite content = new Composite(bar, SWT.NONE);
    content.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final StyledText text = new StyledText(content, SWT.BORDER);
    item.setControl(content);
    item.setHeight(content.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y);

    mapping.put(item, text);
}
```

Comment: Tank you!
Can you explain why manually setting the expanded status of the item to true does not work?

Comment: @user2951712 You mean when you expand it from code it doesn't set the focus?

Comment: yes, if I use 
item.setExpanded(true);
bar.layout();

Comment: @user2951712 Updated my code with an example how to expand the item from code and still focus on the `StyledText`.